# The argument type 'List<HospitalListModel>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'HospitalListModel'

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

i have bloc class and it throw an error with a message `The argument type 'List<HospitalListModel>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'HospitalListModel'.`

this is the bloc class:

```
class HospitalListBloc extends Bloc<HospitalListEvent, HospitalListState> {
  HospitalListBloc() : super(HospitalListInitial()) {
    final ApiRepository _apiRepository = ApiRepository();

    on<GetCovidList>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        emit(HospitalListLoading());
        final mList = await _apiRepository.fetchHospitalList();
        emit(HospitalListLoaded(mList));
      } on NetworkError {
        emit(HospitalListError("Failed to fetch data. is your device online?"));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and the error is on `emit(HospitalListLoaded(mList));`, and in case if you want to know the API provider:

```
class ApiProvider {
  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  final String _url = 'http://lovemonster.my.id/hospital';

  Future<List<HospitalListModel>?> fetchHospitalList() async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
      return hospitalListModelFromJson(response.data);
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
      return Future.error("");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `HospitalListLoaded` probably accepts `HospitalListModel`, but you are passing the whole `List` of `HospitalListModel`s on the line `emit(HospitalListLoaded(mList));`

Answer (score 0):

your HospitalListLoaded function should be

```
HospitalListLoaded(List<HospitalListModel> mList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an **Object of HospitalListModel** but your Bloc class having method which accept **list of HospitalListModel**

You need to return list not an object

Check below code which will be useful

```
  class ApiProvider {
          final Dio _dio = Dio();
          final String _url = 'http://lovemonster.my.id/hospital';
        
          Future<List<HospitalListModel>?> fetchHospitalList() async {
            try {
  List<HospitalListModel> hospitalList = [];
              Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
  var mData = responseData.data as List;
              hospitalList =  mData.
                  .map<HospitalListModel?>((e) => hospitalListModelFromJson(e)
                  .toList(); 
return hospitalList;//return List not object
            } catch (error, stacktrace) {
              print("Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
              return Future.error("");
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: im sorry but there's another alert "Exception occurred: type '(dynamic) => List<HospitalListModel>' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => HospitalListModel' of 'f' stackTrace: #0      ApiProvider.fetchHospitalList (package:hospitallist/resources/provider/api_provider.dart:13:10)" and i think it because List<HospitalListModel> hospitalListModelFromJson(String str) => List<HospitalListModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => HospitalListModel.fromJson(x)));

Comment: @fairycatto check updated code you can adjust null safety on your hand

Comment: where did you get the  responseData from mData, because it's not initialized yet

Comment: oh sorry, i think it's response.data, but now it showing another alert that says "A value of type 'Iterable<HospitalListModel>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<HospitalListModel>?'. (Documentation)"

Comment: @fairycatto can you add your full code because issue in not in fetchHospitalList() it is in another class/method

Comment: if you don't mind, you can check my whole code on my file project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pDgZWs0hLlDnlddoccjyqqzhhDvJpy01/view?usp=sharing it's only simple project that consists 2 screen

Comment: hello, can you check my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74858448/a-value-of-type-iterablehospitallistmodel-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of im already add another code on there, i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

> The argument type 'List<HospitalListModel>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'HospitalListModel'.

Your `HospitalListLoaded` function is declared as this:

```
void HospitalListLoaded(HospitalListModel model){
    ....
}
```

Here the parameter type is a single `HospitalListModel`, not a list of them. So, you can either pass a single `HospitalListModel` or you can change the parameter type to `List<HospitalListModel>`. In that case, you must change your logic inside that function.

Plus, notice the `?` null operator. If the `List` you pass can be null, then the parameter type must be nullable. In that case,

```
void HospitalListLoaded(List<HospitalListModel>? models){
    ....
}
```